# Pass ArrayList from to Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, arraylist, serializable

I have an `ArrayList` of `CustomInput` objects and `DataWrapper` class with getter and setter for the `ArrayList`. I want to pass `DataWrapper` from Non-Activity class to Activity class. I have tried implementing Serializable, but I get *Parcelable encountered ioexception writing serializable object* cause by *NotSerializableException*.

**DataWrapper.java**

```
public class DataWrapper implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private ArrayList<CustomInput> customInputs;

public void setFields(ArrayList<CustomInput> data) {
    this.customInputs = data;
}

public ArrayList<CustomInput> getFields() {
    return this.customInputs;
}
}
```

**Non-Activiy class**

```
public void showActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(request, ActivityKorak.class);
    intent.putExtra("title", title);
    DataWrapper dw = new DataWrapper();
    dw.setFields(fields);
    intent.putExtra("data", dw);

    request.startActivity(intent);
}
```

**ActivityKorak.class->onCreate()**

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
    DataWrapper dw = (DataWrapper) intent.getSerializableExtra("data");
    ArrayList<CustomInput> fields = dw.getFields();
```

Comment: hi why you create array list inside Serializable.It automatically work in form of array.

Comment: if you want to do with Serializable  then i'll give you example how it work

Comment: I just want to pass ArrayList to Activity and I don't have to use DataWrapper.

Comment: i have added my answer can try once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to create new class **DataWrapper.java**. Because **ArrayList** is serializable.

**Non-Activiy class**

```
public void showActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(request, ActivityKorak.class);
    intent.putExtra("title", title);
    intent.putExtra("data", fields);

    request.startActivity(intent);
}
```

**ActivityKorak.class->onCreate()**

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
    DataWrapper dw = (DataWrapper) intent.getSerializableExtra("data");
    ArrayList<CustomInput> fields = dw.getFields();
```

Answer (score 0):

hi please check how we can send arraylist in intent

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> aldata = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

i assumed here data is already added in your arraylist, please check

Send data and start other activity,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,AbcActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("aldata", aldata_TaxiLine);
startActivity(intent);
```

Get data in your next activity,

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> aldata1;
```

and call this in your oncreate

```
    aldata = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) getIntent()
            .getSerializableExtra("aldata");
```

hope this will help you.